# Firestore Pagination : StartAfter query with DocumentSnapshot not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of offers/deals saved in my firestore database.  I want to fetch the first 3 deals sorted by discount in desc order i.e the deals with highest discount comes first and then next highest and so on. I am fetching them in segments of 3.

[image: How i sorted them firebase console]

[image: My sorted database based on discount]

I am trying to achieve the same using android code. So, that the first 3 elements with discount 55,44,28 should come first, later 27,27,21 and finally 19,4.

```
class ContentGenerationActivityV1 : AppCompatActivity() {

     var lastDocument : DocumentSnapshot?= null
     lateinit var filterQuery: Query

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_generation)

        val doc = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("steal-deals").document("deals")

       filterQuery = doc.collection(getTodayTimeStamp().toString())
        .orderBy("discount", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

       filterFetchButton.setOnClickListener {
           if(lastDocument == null){
              fetchFirstFew()
           } else {
            fetchMore()
        }
    }
}

//Get first 3 elements
fun fetchFirstFew(){

    Log.d("N/W CALL ::", "FIRST")

    filterQuery.limit(3) .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            lastDocument = result.documents.last()

            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("DEAL :: ", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }

        }


}

//Get the next 3 elements
fun fetchMore(){

    Log.d("N/W CALL ::", "SECOND")

    filterQuery.startAfter(lastDocument)
        .limit(3).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            lastDocument = result.documents.last()

            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("DEAL :: ", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }


        }
}
```

But it is always returning the first three elements (55,44,28) no matter what.[image]

Please guide me so in achieving the same.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** out. Is in Java but I think you'll understand. It's a straightforward example.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. You might want to set a breakpoint in `fetchMore` and run it in a debugger, to see if `lastDocument` has the correct value.

Comment: I checked the `lastDocument` value twice and the i can confirm that the value was correct.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it yet? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but after some research found out the "startAfter(lastDocument)" returns a new Query instance which you need to get and on that you need to call limit.

```
val query = filterQuery.startAfter(lastDocument)
query.limit(3).get().addOnSuccessListener {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought startAfter was mutating the existing one

Answer (score 1):

In addition to storing query object in separate reference, you also need to make sure that you are passing the **non-null**  lastDocument to  startAfter. You can either cast it to as Document Snapshot or put !! at the variable end

```
filterQuery.startAfter(lastDocument!!)
    .limit(3).get()
```

OR

```
filterQuery.startAfter(lastDocument as DocumentSnapshot)
    .limit(3).get()
```

It will surely work

Answer (score 0):

i just got this issue.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794553/7531626)

so, in your code

Wrong:

```
filterQuery.limit(3) .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            lastDocument = result.documents.last()

            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("DEAL :: ", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }

        }
```

True:

```
filterQuery = filterQuery.limit(3) .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            lastDocument = result.documents.last()

            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("DEAL :: ", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }

        }
```

because when you chaining to query, it creates and returns a new Query that starts after the provided document (exclusive). so you have to reassign it!